# Is there any reason a file would read the type of a column differently when they are in different directories?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently compiling daily .txt files over the course of two years for a project. I first wrote code to take each day as a dataframe and append each one to a dictionary by season, to analyze later. This technique works for all except one file; it reads certain columns that should be floats as strings. There are over 100 files in the subset of the files I'm looking at per season.

When I make a copy of that same file, place it in my desktop instead of a particular directory, and load that one file the same way, it the numbered columns reads as a float as it should.

I realize I can bypass my problem  by simply replacing the correctly loaded file into the dictionary; however, I worry that this error could be indicative of a larger systematic error.

Here's the code that loads it to the dictionary:

```
path = '/Users/ET/Desktop/Summer_1314/'
column_names = ['col1', 'col1', 'col3']
dict_of_df = {}

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    split_up = filename.split('_')
    year_string = split_up[4][:2]
    if filename.startswith('A') and year_string == '13':
        daily_df = pd.read_fwf(path + filename, header = None, names = column_names)
        daily_df = daily_df.drop(columns = [col1, col2])
        dict_of_df[split_up[4]] = daily_df

for keys, df in dict_of_df.items():
    print(keys, df.dtypes)
```

Here is the result of calling .dtypes to the off-day using the code above:

```
col3       object
col4       object
col5       object
col6       object
dtype: object
```

Here it is by loading the file by itself, outside of the loop:

```
col3       float64
col4       float64
col5       float64
col6       float64
dtype: object
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Without a [mcve] it will be very difficult for anyone to answer your question. Please check the code that you posted as it appears to have several typos, e.g: `column_names = ['col1', 'col1', 'col3']` (`'col1'` repeated and  and the other column names missing) and `daily_df = daily_df.drop(columns = [col1, col2])` (`col1` and `col2` should probably be strings) and post a sample of the datafile in question. How are you copying the files? Are you using the OS copy function, or opening it in a program and saving a new copy?

Comment: That's a fair point; I will post a new question with these in mind

Comment: There is no need to post a new question. Just edit this one to address the points above.